# O(n^log n) algorithm for collision detection

Tags: c++, algorithm, collision-detection, time-complexity

I'm building a game engine and I was wondering: are there any algorithms out there for Collision Detection that have time complexity of O(N^log N)?

I haven't written any coding yet, but I can only think of a O(N^2) algorithm (ie: 2 for-loops looping through a list of object to see if there's collision).

Any advice and help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spatial partitioning can create O(n log(n)) solutions. Depending on the exact structure and nature of your objects, you'll want a different spatial partitioning algorithm, but the most common are octrees and BSP.

Basically, the idea of spatial partitioning is to group objects by the space they occupy. An object in node Y can never collide with an object in node X (unless X is a subnode of Y or vice versa). Then you partition the objects by which go in which nodes. I implemented an octree myself.

Comment: "An object in node Y can never collide with an object in node X" - That's not quite correct, you must 1. ensure the partitions are at least the size of the interaction length (e.g. size of largest object) 2. then also check the nearest neighbors of the current domain. Else two objects in neighboring domains could pass through eachother as long as their positions are separated by a domain boundary.

Comment: @DerManu: No, that's what you use the non-leaf nodes of your octree for.

Answer (score 2):

You can minimize the number of checks by sorting the objects into areas of space.
( There is no point in checking for a collision between an object near 0,0 and one near 1000,1000 )

The obvious solution would be to succesively divide your space in half and use a tree ([BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)) structure. Although this works best for sparse clouds of objects, otherwise you spend all the time checking if an object near a boundary hits an object just on the other side of the boundary

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a restricted interaction length, i.e. when two objects are a certain distance, there is no more interaction.
If that is so, you normally would divide your space into domains of appropriate size (e.g. interaction length in each direction). Now, for applying the interaction to a particle, all you need to do is go through its own domain and the nearest neighbor domains, because all other particles are guaranteed further away than the interaction length is. Of course, you must check at particle updates whether any domain boundary is crossed, and adjust the domain membership accordingly. This extra bookkeeping is no problem, considering the enormous performance improvement due to the lowered interacting pair count.
For more tricks I suggest a scientific book about numerical N-Body-Simulation.

Of course each domain has its own list of particles that are in that domain. There's no use having a central list of particles in the simulation and going through all entries to check on each one whether it's in the current or the neighboring domains.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using oct-tree for positions in 3D, which can be quite in-homogeneously distributed. The tree (re-)build is usually quite fast, bot O(N log(N)). Then finding all collisions for a given particle can be done in O(K) with K the number of collisions per particle, in particular there is no factor log(N). So, to find all collisions then need O(K*N), after the tree build.